# Adding UIButton in each UICollectionViewCell in Scrolling Filmstrip within UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

First off, let me describe the scenario I've got so far. Here's the basic rundown of how my UICollectionView in Scrolling Filmstrip style within UITableView works:

- Create a normal **UITableView** with a custom **UITableViewCell**
- Create a custom **UIView** that will be added to the cell's **contentView**
- The custom **UIView** will contain a **UICollectionView**
- The custom **UIView** will be the datasource and delegate for the **UICollectionView** and manage the flow layout of the **UICollectionView**
- Use a custom **UICollectionViewCell** to handle the collection view data
- Use NSNotification to notify the master controller's **UITableView** when a collection view cell has been selected and load the detail view.

[image]

So far, I've been able to create those described above but as you can see in the picture I also want to add an UIButton in each **UICollectionViewCell** so that when I tap the UIButton its image will change to checked mark and data in that **UICollectionViewCell** will be saved into an array. At the end, when I tap the top-right triangle button it will push to another view with the array that saves selected data passed on.

Here're all the relevant classes that I've got:

**UITableView**

- *ViewController.h*
- *ViewController.m*

**UIView**

- *ContainerCellView.h*
- *ContainerCellView.m*

**UICollectionViewCell**

- *CollectionViewCell.h*
- *CollectionViewCell.m*

**UITableViewCell**

- *ContainerCell.h*
- *ContainerCell.m*

**My question is that I can't get my UIButton at least to show up (for now)** with this below code:

*ContainerCellView.m*

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *cellData = [self.collectionData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    ...

    //  >>> Select Button <<<

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 60)];
    [button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button]; //???

    //  >>> End Select Button <<<<

    ...

    return cell;
}
```

*ContainerCell.m*

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        _collectionView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContainerCellView" owner:self options:nil][0];
        _collectionView.frame = self.bounds;
        [self.contentView addSubview:_collectionView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**What have I done wrong and how should I do this better?** If you need more info, you're more than welcome to request. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:200]` returning what you expect?

Comment: @jrisberg you got me right on this. That's left from my old context and I overlooked it. Now I replaced it with `UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];` and the button is shown. I'll accept your comment as an answer if you just make it one. Thanks!

Comment: Cool glad you got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:200]` is returning what you expect, a new button here would serve your purpose.